# Return an object using ResponseEntity with JSONObject as one of the object's field

Tags: json, rest, spring-restcontroller, objectmapper

My model looks like below, where in bookJson is a json object -

```
{
    "name" : "somebook",
    "author" : "someauthor"
}

public class Book{
    private int id;
    private JSONObject bookJson;

   public int getId(){return this.id;}
   public JSONObject getBookJson(){this.bookJson;}
   public void setId(int id){this.id = id;}
   public void setBookJson(JSONObject json){this.bookJson = json;}

}
```

JSONObject belongs to org.json package

When My RestController returns Book object in a ResponseEntity object , I get the error -

```
 "errorDesc": "Type definition error: [simple type, class org.json.JSONObject]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Can we not achieve this without having to have a model class with all fields of bookJson?

Comment: how are you sending this object from controller layer?

Comment: As a List<Book>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.

Added JSONObject as a Map instead and used ObjectMapper to do all the conversions.

```
public class Book{
    private int id;
    private Map<String, Object>bookJson;

   public int getId(){return this.id;}
   public Map<String, Object>getBookJson(){this.bookJson;}
   public void setId(int id){this.id = id;}
   public void setBookJson(Map<String, Object> json){this.bookJson = json;}

}



 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new JsonParsingException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) of `List<Book>` type.

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> doSomething() {
  return new ResponseEntity(bookList);
}
```

Comment: This does not work if we use JSONObject as one of the types. Changed it to Map and it worked - check answer below